# Counterintuitive topological result concerning connectedness

Tags: general-topology, geometry, analysis, connectedness

**Problem**

If we consider $A,B,C,D$ to be the corners of the square $[0,1]^2$ where $A$ and $C$ are diagonally opposite (and so are $B$ and $D$). Then we can define $X$ to be a connected subset of the square containing A and C and we can defined $Y$ to also be a connected subset of the square containing $B$ and $D$.

We want to find out whether or not X and Y can be disjoint.

**Concerns**

Intuitively, it feels also there must be some overlap, however, the answer is that they can indeed by disjoint. I have been trying to to understand how this is the case, however, it feels extremely counterintuitive based on the fact that lines connecting both A and C, and B and D within the square seem to be impossible to draw without crossing at some point.

**Question**

I would like to be gain an insight into how this could be true and where the gap in my ability to visualise this problem is coming from.

Comment: Your intuition comes from path-connectedness and, indeed, there are no such path-connected subsets.

Comment: What would be a better way to think about the problem diagrammatically? @MoisheKohan

Comment: Consider how the [topologist's sine curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve) can be modified to find an example here where $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint.

Comment: Are you familiar with the actual mathematical details of the example of $X$ and $Y$? Have you stared at that construction and brutally tried to understand it? Sometimes that kind of brutality is the only way to puncture one's incorrect intuition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A=(0,0), B=(0,1),C=(1,1),D=(1,0).$

We use the following theorems:

(T1). If $F$ is a family of connected sets and $\cap F\ne \emptyset$ then $\cup F$ is connected.

(T2). If $P$ is a connected set and $\overline P\supseteq Q\supseteq P$ then $Q$ is connected.

Let $X_0=[0,1)\times \{0\}$ and $Y_0=[0,1)\times \{1\}.$

For $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $X_n=X_{n-1}\cup (\{1-2^{-n}\}\times [0,1-2^{-n}])$ and let $Y_n=Y_{n-1}\cup (\{1-3^{-n}\}\times [3^{-n},1]).$

Let $X'=\cup_{n\ge 0}X_n$ and let $Y'=\cup_{n\ge 0}Y_n.$ Let $X=X'\cup \{C\}$ and let $Y=Y'\cup \{D\}.$

Now $X'$ and $Y'$ are each connected sets by (T1) with $F=\{X_n:n\ge 0\}$ or $F=\{Y_n:n\ge 0\}.$

Since $X'$ and $Y'$ are connected sets, $X$ and $Y$ are connected sets by (T2), because $C\in\overline {X'}$ and $D\in\overline {Y'}$.

Comment: Woah that's insane

Comment: I guess it's really just a matter of drawing two disjoint sequences of points $c_n$ and $d_n$ approaching $C$ and $D$, and taking turns connecting $A$ to $c_1$, $B$ to $d_1$, $A$ to $c_2$, $B$ to $d_2$, etc, at each step taking care not to intersect anything from the other sequence that's been drawn so far

Comment: Inspired by this, I created my own variant: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AE7m5.jpg (Though based on Greg's comment, I'm guessing this is one of the standard examples.) I mean for neither curve to be closed; they each only contain one point of the left edge. …Incidentally, is this impossible with closed sets?

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger . It is impossible with closed sets.  If $X,Y$ are disjoint, closed and connected, there is a disjoint pair $U,V$ of open path-connected subsets of the square with $X\subset U$ and $Y\subset V.$  So let $f:[0,1]\to U$ and $g:[0,1]\to V$ be continuous  with $f(0)=A, f(1)=C, g(0)=B,g(1)=D.$  But this implies there exists $x$ with $f(x)=g(x)\in U\cap V,$ a contradiction, as $U, V$ are disjoint.

Comment: Another example: https://i.imgur.com/w3C4eBA.jpg where each color contains at least one point on the limit line.